# sass failing - wrong number of arguments... but they are there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

We run a build every night. Last night, the build started failing on the precompile assets step, the reason:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) for `darken'
```

The line in question:

```
$green: #61c256;
$green-dark: darken($green, 10%);
```

Not only is the line syntactically correct, but this line has also not changed for *months*. In fact if I roll back the assets to the day before, it fails for the same reason!

So it's not the scss itself.

Does anyone know what could possibly cause this? The javascript precompiles okay it's just when it gets to the css. We haven't updated any gems, and there were a LOT of commits yesterday.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Running Rails 3.2

Comment: Hold on chaps and chapettes, might be homing in on the problem, will paste answer when found. If it's what I think it is, you won't be able to solve this for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it turned out to be... although it's unlikely anyone else will encounter this problem, I'll post the resolution here on the off-chance.

Basically, a rake task was written. The developer who wrote the rake task (who shall remain nameless, but it might have been me) decided that it would be nice to have pretty, coloured in  text in the responses to the user when they run this task.

Looking through the rails default dependencies, Thor appears to have methods such as "say" and "say_status", lets use those! The following line was included in the rake task's file:

```
include Thor::Base
```

And it all worked, suddenly the rake task could use the thor methods and have pretty, syntax-highlighted output!

**But including this module breaks most other rake tasks, including the asset precompiler.**

It's always the things you least expect.